# Ignore empty cells in for each VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a problem with my loop(i go throu columns in every worksheet and copy them common column ) in VBA. And I wan't to ignore empty cells... any ideas? Bellow is my code

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lastRowMaster = 1

For Each Ws In Sheets(Array("1L", "5L"))

        lastRow = Ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        Ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Podatki plana").Range("A" & lastRowMaster)
        lastRowMaster = Worksheets("Podatki plana").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Done!"
```

Comment: do you want to ignore empty cells within the range of `A1:A & lastRow`?

Comment: in this case i recommend copying cell by cell

Answer (score 3):

I altered this line of code:

```
Ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Podatki plana").Range("A" & lastRowMaster)
```

To this:

```
Ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Podatki plana").Range("A" & lastRowMaster)
```

Using the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` qualifier selects only cells that have a value in them.  You could change `xlCellTypeConstants` to `xlCellTypeFormulas` or any of the options listed on [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx).

The benefit with this is that you don't have to loop through each cell, which is a perfectly good solution but comes with a performance penalty.

Tested in Excel 2013.

Comment: Thank you very very much

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just set each of the destination cells to the origin cell when the cell is not empty, like so

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lastRowMaster = 1
lastRow = Ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
nextRow = 1
For Each Ws In Sheets(Array("1L", "5L"))     
    for i = 1 to lastRow
        if Not IsEmpty(Ws.Cells(i, 1)) then        
            Worksheets("Podatkiplana").cells(nextRow, 1) = Ws.cells(i,1)
            nextRow = nextRow + 1
        end if
    next i
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Done!"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lastRowMaster = 1

For Each Ws In Sheets(Array("1L", "5L"))

        lastRow = Ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        For i = 1 to lastrow
            lastRowMaster = Worksheets("Podatki plana").Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
            If ws.cells(i, 1)<> "" Then Worksheets("Podatki plana").Cells(lastRowMaster, 1) = ws.cells(i,1) 

        next i  
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Done!"
```

Comment: This answer is similar to mine, but would produce potentially many blank cells. Also it looks like you meant `.cells(i, 1)` not `.cells(1, i)`.

Comment: thank you very much for your hint, when I posted my answer, I didn't see that others were already posted.

Comment: Multiple answers are just fine, in my opinion. I just thought I'd offer suggestions for improvement where yours was concerned.

Comment: No problem, I do often mix up the `cells` property

Comment: Guys... one more question, how about if i need to copy column A and M from "1L" and paste all in A? any sugestions?